# Powershell - Create Scheduled Task to run as local system / service

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

Can anyone tell me how to create a scheduled task using powershell that runs as the local system or local service?

Everything works great except the call to ITaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition().

If I pass in $null, or "", than the call bombs saying invalid username or password.
Any thoughts"

$Rootfolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", $Taskdef, 6, "LOCAL SERVICE", "", 3)

Comment: My answer was deleted here as an identical. So, I only could recommend to look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569045/register-scheduledjob-as-the-system-account-without-having-to-pass-in-credentia/60554216#60554216) as it really doing the thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you would need to use "nt authority\localservice" as the user name.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 17):

For those who can use **PowerShell 3.0** on **Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012**, new cmdlets will let you do it in a simple way when registering your scheduled task with the cmdlet `Register-ScheduledTask` and as argument `-User "System"`

Here is a scheduled task created entirely with PS, its purpose is to restart a service My Service, using the SYSTEM account, 3 minutes after the system has started:

```
$taskname = "Restart My Service"
$taskdescription = "Restart My Service after startup"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' `
  -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& Restart-Service -displayname \"My Service\""'
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay (New-TimeSpan -minutes 3)
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 2) -RestartCount 3 -RestartInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $taskname -Description $taskdescription -Settings $settings -User "System"
```

NB: you will need to run powershell as an administrator for that script.

Comment: I just get:Register-ScheduledTask : Access is denied.
    At line:7 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName $taskname -De ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Register-ScheduledTask], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070005,Register-ScheduledTask

Comment: Never mind.... You have to have the powershell command prompt running as administrator.

Comment: @ColinMackay I updated my answer in order to add a nota bene note about running the script as an admin. Happy that it helped you though and thanks for your comment

Comment: I am getting an error with this, using PS 4.0.  : Register-ScheduledTask : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Password'. The argument is null or empty

Comment: When straight remote powershell doesn't work (hp bios utility), this comes in handy.

Answer (score 6):

This code snippet will use the [PowerShellPack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack)'s Task Scheduler module to schedule a task to run as SYSTEM immediately:

```
New-Task |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Principal.Id = "NTAuthority\SYSTEM"
        $_.Principal.RunLevel = 1
        $_
    } |
    Add-TaskAction -Script {
        "SystemTask" > C:\myTest.txt
    } |
    Add-TaskTrigger -OnRegistration |
    Register-ScheduledTask SystemTask
```

Comment: Thanks Media.  I'll check this out tomorrow.