# Register-ScheduledJob as the system account (without having to pass in credentials)

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, jobs

I believe for `Register-ScheduledTask` you can specify `-User "System"`or do something like:

```
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId SYSTEM -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest
```

How do I do this with `Register-ScheduledJob`?

This command will be running the context of the local admin so it will have access to do this. I just don't see this option in the cmdlet.

[Here is an example of how to do this with the scheduled tasks cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846688/powershell-run-job-at-startup-with-admin-rights-using-scheduledjob)

edit: Does windows make this impossible by design? If I open an interactive PS session as the system (using psexec) and try to create a schedualed job I get an error:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Register-ScheduledJob -Name systemsssss -ScriptBlock {'s
dfsdfsdfsd'}
Register-ScheduledJob : An error occurred while registering scheduled job
definition systemsssss to the Windows Task Scheduler.  The Task Scheduler
error is: (32,4):UserId:.
At line:1 char:1
+ Register-ScheduledJob -Name systemsssss -ScriptBlock {'sdfsdfsdfsd'}
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Power...edJobDefini
   tion:ScheduledJobDefinition) [Register-ScheduledJob], ScheduledJobExceptio
  n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantRegisterScheduledJobDefinition,Microsoft.Pow
   erShell.ScheduledJob.RegisterScheduledJobCommand
```

This same command works fine when run as the local administrator account

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and describe how it does not meet your requirement and what the output should be. Have you tried `-Credential`?

Comment: "without having to specify credentials". I have no example code, because I did not see this an even being an option- though I did see how it can be done with the scheduled tasks cmdlet

Comment: The default is the current user. What code are you using for Register-ScheduledJob and what output does it produce? Please use copy/paste.

Comment: you don't understand my question. I know it runs as the current user, I want to run it in the context of the system. the output is not relevant to my question because there is no output because I don't know how to even create a job in the context of the local system.

Answer (score 7):

First use **Register-ScheduledJob** to create your PowerShell job.

Then use **Set-ScheduledTask** to change a startup account to the *Local System* or any other built-in accounts, i.e. `SYSTEM`, `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE`, etc.

Use the following PS-script. Or download it from my [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/it3xl/c897b2c054e8ed19eb687bd1b9bfbb4c)
The code is self-explanatory (I believe).
You can run it multiple times under an administrative account if you want to check how it works.

BTW, I prefer to use jobs (`Register-ScheduledJob`) over tasks because jobs allow me to embed PowerShell script blocks (strings) instead using of external script files. Look at `-ScriptBlock` below.

Also pay attention to `-RunElevated`. It is a must be.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Clear-Host

#### Start of Main Logic ###########################

$taskName = "my_PowerShell_job"

$accountId = "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM";
#$accountId = "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE";

$task = Get-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($task -ne $null)
{
    Unregister-ScheduledJob $task  -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host " @ The old ""$taskName"" PowerShell job has been unregistered"; Write-Host;
}

# Uncomment the following exit command to only delete your job.
# exit;

# Shchedule your job. Using of -AtStartup as an example.
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup;

$options = New-ScheduledJobOption -StartIfOnBattery  -RunElevated;

Write-Host " @ Registering of ""$taskName"" job";
Register-ScheduledJob -Name $taskName  -Trigger $trigger  -ScheduledJobOption $options `
    -ScriptBlock {
        # Put your code here.
        Write-Host Your job has been launched!;
    }


$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID $accountId `
    -LogonType ServiceAccount  -RunLevel Highest;

$psJobsPathInScheduler = "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs";
$someResult = Set-ScheduledTask -TaskPath $psJobsPathInScheduler `
    -TaskName $taskName  -Principal $principal

#### End of Main Logic ###########################

Write-Host;
Write-Host " @ Let's look at running account of ""$taskName"" PowerShell job"
$task = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName
$task.Principal

Write-Host " @ Let's start ""$taskName"" manually"
Start-Job -DefinitionName $taskName | Format-Table

Write-Host " @ Let's proof that ""$taskName"" PowerShell job has been launched"; Write-Host;
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Receive-Job -Name $taskName
Write-Host;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly you can't run schedule a job or task as the system account.

But you can create local administrator accounts as the system account.

And you can schedule jobs or tasks as a local administrator account.

So what I did to get around this problem is this:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString (New-Guid).Guid -AsPlainText -Force
$user = New-LocalUser "service.scheduler" -Password $Password -Description "For scheduling in tasks from system account"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($user.name, $password)
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $trigger -ScriptBlock $scriptblock -Name $taskName -ScheduledJobOption $options -credential $credentials
```

This does mean you are passing in credentials, but you don't have to store them as plain text or specify them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't make comments with reputation under 50.

Can you use Group Policy to run it as a start up script? That will run as the Local System account. Doesn't look like this cmdlet has the -verb paramater to runas.

Looking at: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849755.aspx under -ScheduledJobOption there is a setting in there RunElevated=$False, that is the defualt. If you set that to true does it run as admin?

I haven't tried it, it might work.

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.