# Install agent remotely using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I am have a list of servers where an agent needs to be installed. For remote installation, I am running the below script from a client machine.

The client machine creates a connection to the remote machine using `New-PSSession` and the script runs without any error, but the installation never happens.

```
$csvFilePath = "C:\Demo\Agent-Installation-Servers.csv"
$aLoginId = "abc@d.com"
$aPassword = "123456"

$urlToDownloadTheAgent = "https://someexample.com"

Import-Csv $csvFilePath | ForEach-Object {
    $hostName = $_.Host
    $loginId = $_.LoginId
    $password = $_.Password

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $loginCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($loginId, $securePassword)

    $sessionOption = New-PsSessionOption –SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck
    $sessionObject = New-PSSession -ComputerName $hostName -Credential $loginCredentials -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessionOption 

    Invoke-Command -Session $sessionObject -ScriptBlock {
        $agentDownloadDirectory = "C:\NewAgent"
        md -Force $agentDownloadDirectory | Out-Null
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlToDownloadTheAgent -OutFile "C:\NewAgent\win.exe"
        & C:\NewAgent\win.exe --no-prompt -u $aLoginId -p $aPassword
    }
}
```

Have also tried replacing

```
  & C:\NewAgent\win.exe --no-prompt -u $aLoginId -p $aPassword
```

with

```
$arguments = "--no-prompt -u $aLoginId -p $aPassword"
start-process "C:\NewAgent\win.exe"  -ArgumentList $arguments
```

Comment: Many installers don't work correctly through remoting, for example because they rely on an interactive session being available, or because of double-hop authentication issues. Consult the event log or any log files the installer produces for more information. There is no universal solution, but a common approach for tasks that can't be run through remoting is to create a temporary scheduled task running as System and invoke that (as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35422915/4137916), for example).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - It looks like the arguments --noprompt, -u & -p are not getting supplied. Bcoz in the task manager, the instance of that exe is displaying. :(

Comment: Whoops. I completely skipped over that. `Invoke-Command` is executed *remotely* and has no access to the script variables you define *locally*. Use `$using:aLoginId` and `$using:aPassword` to pass those. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables). (`--noprompt` is a simple argument and should be passed without trouble.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Any other way to pass the parameters (arguments)

Comment: Well, if you're going to use `-ArgumentList`, you need to pass an actual list, not a string as one argument. `@("--no-prompt", "-u $using:aLoginId", "-p $using:aPassword")`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - That did the trick. Can you please post this as an answer. Will accept it. Cheers !!

Comment: Can you try if a simple `& C:\NewAgent\win.exe --no-prompt -u $using:aLoginId -p $using:aPassword` also works, or is `Start-Process -ArgumentList` required? It ought to do the same thing.